# LINQ in C#. why use IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm learning `LINQ` in C# now. All sources, which i saw all uses `IEnumerable<T>` on left hand. why they use this and don't other types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because all collections are implementing `IEnumerable<T>` *therefore* `LINQ` methods can be used with all collections.`LINQ` is designed to operate on collections so probably they choose to use `IEnumerable<T>` interface because it is common interface for all collection types.

Answer (score 2):

By definition `IEnumerable` is "Exposes an enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection" - since all you get from a query are usually objects of certain type, which are having rows (arrays in generic sense), it makes more sense to use an `IEnumerable<T>` to help iterate through the returned data.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2):

**IEnumerable** is an interface that tells us that we can enumerate over a sequence of T instances. If you need to perform some action for each object in a collection, this is preferable choice.

As per the MSDN
[IEnumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ienumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Exposes an enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a
>   non-generic collection

I also suggest you to go thru this [CodeProject link](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=5&cad=rja&ved=0CD0QFjAE&url=http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/474678/A-Beginners-Tutorial-on-Implementing-IEnumerable-I&ei=-40NU--tKIizrgf4koHABQ&usg=AFQjCNHMPgQv77z4jDSs7NDUvwev7V8bxg)

Answer (score 1):

Two reasons for this.

1. `IEnumerable` is an interface for which no instance can be created. So, it is on the left-side.
2. All the resources which you enumerate in LINQ implement this interface.

Also, this is used when you just want to read an enumeration using an iterator and not do any modifications to it.

Answer (score 0):

In case of `linq` the queries you do on object are not executed immediately. The execution is deferred until iterations to improve the performance. Which means when you do,

```
var filtered = something.where(st=>st.data == mydata);
```

Compiler does not execute the query and retrieve the objects. So, all you can do on `filtered` object is iterate. Other operations (like add, remove etc) does not make sense at this point. And `IEnumerable` provides the perfect interface to serve this purpose.